# How to distinguish between object and const object

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement template linked list in C++, which suppose to have Iterator and ConstIterator (can't modify the list). And I need that the methods been called return an iterator that match the list object. For example if begin() is called with const list it will return ConstIterator, and with non const list it will return Iterator.

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
ConstIterator begin() const;
Iterator begin(); //  ^^^^^
```

Also, you might wanna add `cbegin`:

```
ConstIterator cbegin() const;
```

Comment: thanks. but the question now is - how the compiler know which one to call - by the return value or the word const? and, it means i cant declare functions that return Iterator as const? the function anyway doesnt suppose to modify the list. and also - it means i need to duplicate every method int list class that returns iterator?

Comment: @rooster it uses the overload resolution rules. If you're calling it with a `const` object, it will return a `ConstIterator`. Otherwise, it will return a normal `Iterator`.

Comment: The overload is chosen by the cv-qualifier (i.e. if your object is const, the const-version is used (obviously), if it's non-const, the non-const version is preferred due to a rule which states exactly that). Only *after* the overload resolution, the return type is known. So they don't affect the chosen overload.

Answer (score 2):

Just overload the function:

```
 Iterator getIterator();
 ConstIterator getIterator() const;
```

Answer (score 1):

Plain C++ overloading will accomplish this. i.e.:

```
ConstIterator GetList(const List* x) const { ... }
Iterator GetList(List* x) { ... }
```